# Where is FsConfigWizard.exe on a fresh Windows Server 2012 R2 installation?

Tags: adfs

Having installed this service and realizing I'd configured the wizard incorrectly, I went to re-run it, and couldn't find it!

Doing some searching on Bingle, I found various references to C:\Program Files\Active Directory Federation Services 2.0 and C:\Windows\ADFS, but FsConfigWizard.exe was in neither location on my system.

Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist. You cant invoke the GUI installer again after the role is configured.
You should use the powershell cmdlets to re-configure AD FS.

First server reinstall via install-adfsfarm with -overwriteconfiguration as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479416(v=wps.630).aspx

Additional nodes via add-adfsfarmnode with -overwriteconfiguration as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479385(v=wps.630).aspx

Both links have examples of usage for reference.