# OSname equals Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard but AdfsVersion equals 2.0. How can this be? What to do?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, adfs

Excerpted results from PowerShell query:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AdfsSystemInformation
OSVersion                 : 6.2.9200.0
OSName                    : Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
MachineType               : VMware Virtual Platform
AdfsVersion               : 2.0

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AdfsVersionEx
2.0
```

I have read several places [(the actual quote)](https://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/gathering-architectural-details-from-your-adfs-infrastructure-adfs-version/) [(a second reference)](https://serverfault.com/questions/708666/where-is-fsconfigwizard-exe-on-a-fresh-windows-server-2012-r2-installation) [(a third reference)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d64f25d-dec0-4b2b-b6b1-1b75b57c4aa1/adfs-version-not-able-to-get-the-check?forum=winserverDS) at AD FS 3.0 conforms to this statement: "the file "C:\Windows\ADFS\FSConfig.exe" DOES NOT exist (but the folder "C:\Windows\ADFS" does)". This is true for my server.

It does say Installed.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature ADFS-Federation | FL InstallState
InstallState : Installed
```

Comment: This question was answered in the Superuser community. I'm new here, sorry for the inconvenience. See [this Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1343213/osname-equals-microsoft-windows-server-2012-r2-standard-but-adfsversion-equals-2)

Answer (score 1):

The operating system version 6.2.9200 is Window Server 2012 R1, not R2. You need to provide the output of the PowerShell command: `Get-WindowsFeature ADFS-Federation`. If it doesn't say installed, I would speculate that server was an inplace upgrade from 2008 R2. The built-in ADFS version for Windows Server 2012 R1 is 2.1. The built-in ADFS version for Windows Server 2012 R2 is 3.0.